# Reason for better save capability of QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-2, save

I have an internal processes meeting with work where I am trying to describe the benefits to migrating to QGIS 3 from QGIS 2.

I need to explain the technicalities of how the save option works better for some of the processing tools. In this example I use the dissolve tool:

**QGIS 2.18.14**

[image]

**QGIS 3.2.3**

[image]

I know that QGIS 3 is so much better because you don't have to painfully navigate through your file system and that you have access to the Quick Access Panel, but I just don't know what has changed technically for this to be possible.

Basically I need the technical jargon to explain to them why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS 2 was using the Qt version of the file explorer which was limited in what it offered as well couldn't access native features that you normally can get.

QGIS 3 now uses the native browser based on the OS it's running on in order to give a better experience for the user and allow access to things like you have in the screenshot